# show div in offline event phonegap application

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

i'm using phonegap to create webview application
i used iframe method to get my website

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

then i install cordova-plugin-network-information
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information
and add offline event listener to my javascript code to show div and hide iframe in offline mode

```
    function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 50);
    }
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    function onOffline() {
        $("#iframe").hide();
        $(".error").show();
    }
}
```

it's not working anyway
i reviewed tens of topic but not working for me

i also try this but not working

```
// offline event
function checkConnection() {
           var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
           var states = {};
           states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
           states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
           states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
           states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

           return networkState;

       }

function onDeviceReady() {
       var networkState = checkConnection();
    /* load local files if there is not network connection */
                  if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
                      window.location="offline.html"; 
                  } 
     }
```

Comment: Have you checked that onOffline() function fired at all?

Comment: @AliEsmaeili how to check this , it's my first project with phonegap